# Is the env $LANG setting equivalent to a "magic" utf-8 comment?

Tags: utf-8, ruby-1.9

I had a Ruby script giving me  an `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` error. It turns out the server's `$LANG` env variable was not being set. Once I set it to `en_US.UTF-8`, the error went away.

Does this mean `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` is equivalent to putting `# encoding: UTF-8` on every file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless I'm mistaken, setting:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Only sets the source encoding for that file.

Setting:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Only sets the default external encoding.

Ruby 1.9 has internal, source, and external encodings.